# Python - store a string and an int using map(sys.stdin.readline())

Tags: python, python-2.7

If the input contains a space separated line of int, like-

```
1 3
```

I can map store it in an array using the `map()` function

```
arr = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

or even in two separate variables, by

```
n,m = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

Is there any way to use the same way to read an input line that contains mixed data types. eg.-

```
foo 3
```

where `foo` is a string and `3` is an integer?

Comment: are the numbers alway positive ints?

Comment: Is it expected that the first input is always interpreted as a string and the second input is always interpreted as an integer? If so, that changes how the input should be handled, and none of the answers really deal with that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, no actually the numbers can be negative too, apparently.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, it is always expected that the first input will be a string and the second as an integer (either positive or negative). How does it change how the input should be handled?

Comment: @Deathstroke: I've posted an answer describing how to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always had a string and non negative int:

```
import sys
n, m = map(lambda x: (str, int)[x.isdigit()](x) ,sys.stdin.readline().split(None, 1)) 


print(n,m)
```

But the safest way is always to use a try/except when casting user input even when only expecting one type.

As requested checking for negative is possible:

```
import sys
n, m = map(lambda x: (str, int)[x.isdigit() or x.strip("-").isdigit()](x) ,sys.stdin.readline().split())


print(n, m)
```

But `--10`  `--10--` would also be pass the test but cause an error so again only for your specific case.

Comment: @Deathstroke, yep but really just a fun solution, using a try/except is the safest way, it will also allow for negative numbers.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, but do I need to check for safety if I know for sure that the input will be of the expected form? I mean, I'm going to use this to solve algorithmic problems on online judges. So I guess I should go for something that is faster more than something that is safer?

Comment: @Deathstroke, if it is for something you can be sure of the input always being in that form then sure it is fine. I just meant in general a try is the best approach

Comment: I see. Just out of curiosity, is there any way to also allow negative integers using the lambda function?

Comment: Great answer. Since you are unpacking into `n, m` you may want to eliminate the possibility of a ValueError by limiting the split to 1. ie, `split(None, 1)`

Comment: Even handling negative numbers still isn't really correct. `0123` is all digits, but either not a valid argument to `int` (3.x) or interpreted as octal (2.x). Some Unicode digits are valid in a Python int, and some aren't. `0x12ab` is a valid Python int, but it isn't all digits. Trying to write a function that predicts everything that counts as a valid `int` representation before calling `int` is very hard. If you want any Python `int`, just call `int` with `try`. If you want something different, define exactly what you want, then implement that.

Comment: @abarnert, yes, as I have stated more than once in my answer, in general a try/except is the way to go, the answer is specific to the OP's need which is for online code problem sites not production code.

Comment: I don't see how "online code problem sites" makes a difference here. He says "faster more than something that is safer", but this clearly isn't algorithmically faster or slower, just a tiny constant—plus, a complicated LBYL check is probably going to be slower than try/except anyway. Also, aren't online problems exactly the kind of place where you should expect to see uncommon "trick inputs" that will break naive code?

Comment: @abarnert, not really actually, the multitude of problems I have done have a strict input format, it would be hard to process lines of input if they were random. The input format is literally spelled out on most sites. And again this answer is just for fun not everything in life has to be serious. The question was pretty much hinting at a one liner to do what the OP was already doing which is what I provided along with a recommendation toward using a try/except generally.

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to be _random_, I'd expect them to be carefully chosen by the people writing the tests. For example, I know that Codility (which is used more for interview screening than for contest-type problems) often has questions that test explicitly for bad assumptions like assuming "number" in the problem means "positive integer" when there's no reason to assume that.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not suggesting that your answer is bad, just commenting that the OP shouldn't be looking for "how can I make this even more complicated to avoid using try/except for performance reasons", because it's probably not helping performance, the performance probably isn't relevant, and it's still not complicated enough to be correct.

Comment: @abarnert,  curiosity  is the mother of  discovery.

Answer (score 4):

To do that you should be able to discriminate between strings that can represent integers and strings that cannot. An example is:

```
def foo(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

Then you can normally use `map`:

```
map(foo, sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

The above line for input:

```
abcdef 110
```

will print:

```
['abcdef', 110]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Much cleaner than trying to LBYL whether the number is a valid `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to test whether the string can be cast to an integer number.

```
>>> inpt = "foo 3"
>>> [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in inpt.split()]
```

Of course, you can do the same using `map` and `sys.stdin.readline` using a `lambda`

```
>>> map(lambda s: int(s) if s.isdigit() else s, sys.stdin.readline().split())
foo 4
['foo', 4]
```

If you want to support all sorts of data types, you can try to [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and fall back to the basic string if that does not work.

```
import ast
def try_eval(string):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(string)
    except ValueError:
        return string

>>> map(try_eval, "42 3.14 foo 'bar' [1,2,3]".split())
[42, 3.1400000000000001, 'foo', 'bar', [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: `isdigit` doesn't actually test whether the string can be cast to an integer number, so you shouldn't use it for that purpose.

Comment: @abarnert I am aware that `isdigit` does not handle negative numbers, but is there a case where `isdigit` will return `True` and casting to `int` will fail?

Comment: Off the top of my head, in wide builds of at least some versions of 2.x, non-BMP Unicode digits pass `isdigit` but are rejected by `int`. Meanwhile, there are other things `isdigit` doesn't handle besides negative numbers, like `"+3"` and `" 2 "`, and non-BMP Unicode digits in narrow builds of 3.0-3.2. I have no idea whether these are the only cases. But that in itself is a reason not to use it: "I think these may be the only problems to test for" just means "I can't figure out how to write complete test coverage". By contrast, `try` around `int` is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2):

`map` is for when you want to apply the same transformation to every element of the input. That doesn't fit your use case; you want to treat the two inputs in different ways. Since the data has a fixed format of string, then integer, it'd be best to parse it in a way that always produces that format:

```
x, y = raw_input().split()
y = int(y)
```

If you have more columns, you could make a list of which function to use to handle each column:

```
handlers = [str, int, int, str, float, int, int]
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = [f(x) for (f, x) in zip(handlers, raw_input().split())]
```

The solutions suggested by the other answers don't account for the fixed format of the input. If the user inputs

```
31 42
```

`x` should be `"31"`, not `31`, and if the user inputs

```
foo bar
```

that should be detected as an error, rather than assigning `"bar"` to `y`.

Comment: It doesn't actually seem clear from the question whether he's asking for this or the other answer… so it's definitely worth pointing out, whether it is what he actually wants or not.

Comment: @abarnert: From the clarification in the comments, I'm pretty sure this is the right interpretation, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @user2357112 and @abarnet: For clarification, I'd like state that the format for the input that I'm expecting is always in the form of `foo 42` or `foo -42`.
The input won't contain `32 42` or `foo bar`. It is always in the format of `str int`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a quick "try / except" setup if you're not looking for anything fancy.

e.g.,

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        f = float(x)
        i = int(f)
        x = i if i == f else f
    except:
        pass
    return x

arr = map(convert, sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

Comment: Ah, yes. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Well it works for me. 'abc 123 4.5 6.7' returns ['abc', 123, 4.5, 6.7]. Can you explain what I'm missing?

Comment: @AMacK: Not what you originally asked, but… converting to int via float is not always the same as converting to int directly, nor is it a good idea. Try it with `'100000000000000000000000'` and you'll get `[99999999999999991611392]`.